# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: missing user password

Tags: android, exception, parse-platform

I am getting this error while trying to save data to parse.

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: missing user password

This is my application class

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Register Subclass
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(One.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Two.class);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "app_key", "client_key");

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Testing", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e==null)
                    System.out.println("Subscribed Successfully");
                else
                e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Unable to Subscribe");
            }
        });

        //To save the current device on Parse Installation
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your login code?

Comment: I am using anonymous user( ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser()) only.